# Login with google using angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, google-api, google-oauth

I create the api `http://localhost:3001/api/v1/user/google` for login with google. The api endpoint and client application doing the following..

- user click on the link `http://localhost:3001/api/v1/user/google`
- the endpoint  `http://localhost:3001/api/v1/user/google` first generate an redirect uri and then it take user the google login page
- user login with their credential
- Then it get the token and then request for user information , after getting user information it return user data as json.

**But the problem is:** 
when user click on the link it take user on the google login page, but after that it does not go back to my client app. it stay on the `http://localhost:3001/api/v1/user/google` page. how can i solve the problem. i need to show those json data in my client app.

**API Code** https://gist.github.com/kousherAlam/35b89af266cd156ed129c92532066d97

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: This may help: https://codinglatte.com/amp/posts/angular/sign-in-with-google-angular/

Comment: What's your set redirectUri? Also you don't need a Backend for google Oauth login, you can do it simply with a plugin, I work very often with this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-6-social-login

Comment: @MichaelB hi michael, the redirect uri is autogenerated google login .. More accurately it is the second screenshot uri, In my case i need the backend for google cause it not only need the login it also need user permission to do some other task for user. I'm just wondering how google take user another tab when they are click `login with google` and after login take user to previous tab with the login status.

Comment: hi @nircraft in your solution they use a plugin,In my case i just want to know the technique behind the plugin. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @kousheralampranto that will be what the redirectUri is for, is it currently configured to be where you want to consume the login data? (the frontend)? you also need to specificy the redirectUri together with the login request + whitelist it inside the google api dashboard

Comment: @MichaelB , I'm sorry, I don't understand your point.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kousherAlam/35b89af266cd156ed129c92532066d97

Comment: around line 25-26 of that example, you have to provide, as you provide 'scopes' a property called 'redirectUri' where you specify where you want google to redirect the user after login. As an extra step for security and other stuff, you have to register/whitelist with google that 'redirectUri' option, example from an app I have inside google api dashboard: https://i.imgur.com/dpiagQI.png

Comment: Hey @MichaelB thank you very much, that was the final missing piece. Now my workflow is, first user click the link it take the user to google login page, then google send user to the client app with the code, then i request another route with the code which is responsible for exchange code with token then send back the user data.

Comment: so it works? yay!

Comment: yes it did bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Around line 25-26 of the code example you posted in comments, you have to provide as you provide the 'scopes' property, another property called 'redirectUri'.

This is where you specify where you want google to redirect the user after login.

As an extra step for security reasons and probably some other reasons, you have to register/whitelist with google that 'redirectUri' option, [here is a screenshot of how that interface looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLLsN.png), taken from an app I have inside [Google API Dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials).